# Keep running Jupyter notebook if VPN is disconnected

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use a company VPN like many others for work. We have Jupyterhub installed on the Kubernetes cluster accessed via `ip_address:port`. The ip_adress can only be accessed if VPN is connected.

My company's VPN disconnects after 9 hours. The jupyter notebooks running on the hub also stop running. How do I keep the notebooks running even after I reconnect VPN?